# Creating indexes for optimizing the execution of Stored Prcocedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

The WHERE clause of one of my queries looks like this:

```
and tbl0.Type = 'Alert' 
AND (tbl0.AccessRights like '%'+TblCUG0.userGroup+'%' 
     or tbl0.AccessRights like 'All' )
AND (tbl0.ExpiryDate > CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 1)  
     or tbl0.ExpiryDate is null)
order by tbl0.Priority,tbl0.PublishedDate desc, tbl0.Title asc
```

I will like to know on which columns can I create indexes and which type of index will best suit. Also I have heard that indexes dont work with Like and Wild cards at the starting. So what should be the approach to optimize the queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1    and tbl0.Type = 'Alert' 
2    AND (tbl0.AccessRights like '%'+TblCUG0.userGroup+'%' 
3         or tbl0.AccessRights like 'All' )
4    AND (tbl0.ExpiryDate > CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 1)  
5         or tbl0.ExpiryDate is null)
```

most likely, you will not be able to use an index with a `WHERE` clause like this.

**Line 1**, You could create an index on `tbl0.Type`, but if you have many rows and few actual values, SQL Server will just skip the index and table scan anyway.  Also, having nothing to do with the index issue, a column like this, a code/flag value is better as a fixed width value char(1), tiny int, etc, where "A"=alert or 1=alert.  I would name the column XyzType, where Xyz is what the type describes (DoctorType, CarType, etc). I would create a new table XyzTye, with a FK back to this column in tb10.  this new table would have two columns XyzType PK and XyzDescription, where you expand out the name.

**Line 2**, are you combining multiple values into `tbl0.AccessRights`? and trying to use the `LIKE` to find values within it?  if so, split this out into a different table and then you can remove the like and possibly add an index there.

**Line 3**, `OR` kills an index usage.  Imagine looking through the phone book for all names that are "Smith" or start with "G", you can't just use the index. You may try splitting the query into a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` around the OR so an index can be used (one part looks for "Smith" and the other part looks for "G").  You have not provided enough of the query to determine if this is possible or not in your case.  You many need to use a derived table that contains this `UNION` so you can join it to the rest of your query.

**Line 4**, `tbl0.ExpiryDate` could benifit from a index, but the `or` will kill its usage, see the Line 3 comment.

**Line 5**, you may try the `OR` union trick discussed above, or just not use `NULL`, put in a a default like '01/01/3000' so you don't need the `OR`.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server's Database Tuning Advisor can suggest which indexes will optimize your query, including covering indexes that will optimize the selected columns that you do not include in your query. Just because you add an index doesn't mean that the query optimizer will use it. Some indexes may cost more to use than others, so the optimizer will choose the bext indexes using the underlying tables' statistics. 
Out-of-hand you could use add all ordering and criteria columns to an index, but that would be useless if for example, there are too few distinct Priority values to make it worth the storage.

You are right about LIKE and wildcards. An index is a btree which means that it can speed quick searches for specific values or range queries. A wildcard at the beginning means that the query will have to touch all records to check whether they match the pattern. A wildcard at the end means that the query will only have to touch items that start with the substring up to the wildcard, partially turning this into a range query that can benefit from an index.